# Absent any indication one way or the other, are groups presumed to be majority rule or unanimous descision?

Tags: parliamentary-procedure

cite case law.  Is there a difference between jurisdiction?  Does size and type of group matter? Statutory vs private boards makes a difference?

Comment: In Maine, at least, [it depends on the size of the group](http://law.stackexchange.com/q/4714/333).

Comment: @phoog That link you provided actually does specify that groups of 3 or more may use a majority.  The questioner is asking for when it is not specified.

Comment: @Mr.A that Maine statute is for situations "when the statute, charter or ordinance does not otherwise specify."  So it seems to be just what the questioner seeks.  If that statute constitutes "specification" for the purpose of this question then all that's left is common law.  But any common law rule on this question would also have been specified at some point, by a judge.

Comment: It's not.  I am the questioner.  My phone has a different gmail account connected to it.

Answer (score 2):

A "group" is a rather Ill-defined concept.

If the group is a familial or social group then their decisions are not legally binding so it doesn't matter.

If the group is the creature of a contract then the contract will tell you. If the contract is silent then a decision would amount to a renegotiation of the contract and would have to be unanimous.

If the group is a creature of statute (e.g. company boards, incorporated associations etc.) then the statute will tell you. The statute may tell you that the group can create its own rules. There may also be different levels of majority specified (simple, 2/3, 3/4 etc.) and also if it is a majority of the whole or just those in attendance.

So, yes, jurisdiction matters; yes, size matters and yes; type matters,

Comment: Suppose the statute or the contract failed to mention the number required in order for an action to take place.

Comment: So the question is "what is the law when there is no law?"

Comment: right.  what does the common law say then

Comment: Can't say without a jurisdiction: each has its own common law

Comment: that's an answer in itself

Comment: i'd be interested in the common law reasoning though for a jurisdiction that says unanimous and also for a jurisdiction that says majority and also for if there's a jurisdiction that says something else.  as a bonus (though this is not all im interested in), i'd be interested to know where the unanimity for juries comes from...statute or jurisprudence derived from due process (common law)